# Simple Angular JS Contact Form Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am working on a simple contact form, which is driving me nuts. The HTML is as simple as this:

```
<form name="contactForm" ng-submit="contactForm.$valid && vm.submit()" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" name="name" ng-minlength="1" max="20"
                               ng-model="vm.data.name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="email" ng-minlength="1" placeholder="Email address" name="contactemail"
                               ng-model="vm.data.contactemail" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.subject" name="subject" ng-minlength="1" id=""
                               placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="vm.data.message" name="message" ng-minlength="1"
                                  placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The ng-submit="contactForm.$valid && vm.submit()" should be submitting to a function vm.submit() inside my ContactController as follows:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('xyz')
  .controller('ContactController', ContactController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function ContactController($rootScope,$stamplay,Page,toastr,$log) {
  alert('BOO!');

var vm = this;
vm.data = {};

$rootScope.data = vm.data;

vm.submit = function (){
  alert('BOO!');
  $stamplay.Object("contact")
  .save(vm.data)
  .then(onSuccess, onError);
};

var onSuccess = function () {
  toastr.success('Your message has been delivered!');
};

var onError = function () {
  toastr.error('Seems to be a problem');
};

$rootScope.Page = Page;
Page.setTitle('WHDS | Contact');
Page.setDescription('How to contact us here at the surgery');

// FOR DEV

$log.info($rootScope);
}

})();
```

vm is already declared as this, but even when i put an alert inside the submit function, i get nothing.

On my route.js i have the following:

```
.when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'app/contact/contact.html',
    controller: 'ContactController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

Which is the correct template, controller name and controller as. With all of this seemingly correct, i cannot see why the form would not submit. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ng-submit enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events.  contactForm.$valid is a truthy check not a function that can be called.  Remove it from ng-submit and add ng-disabled="!contactForm.$valid" to your submit button.

Comment: You could also `ng-submit="vm.submit(contactForm)"` and check in the submit function if the given form is valid.

Comment: @jbrown thanks for your comments. I've given it a go, but no dice. Also i'm not sure vm.data is actually collecting anything. I've tried doing $log.info($rootScope) but its just an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the injection of dependencies in your controller.  Add this injection statement after your function declaration:

```
ContactController.$inject=['$rootScope', '$stamplay', 'Page', 'toastr', '$log'];
```

Also, ng-submit enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events. contactForm.$valid is a truthy check not a function that can be called. Remove it from ng-submit and add ng-disabled="!contactForm.$valid" to your submit button, like this:

```
<form name="contactForm" ng-submit="vm.submit()" novalidate>
```

and

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!contactForm.$valid"/>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vd7q7jU3eOIt5cFpWVC6?p=preview) with some of the dependencies ($stamplay, Page, toastr, and $log) stripped out so that I could get to the real issue.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer. I am using the Swiipe framework - https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/blob/master/docs/usage.md - I thought, because of the file structure  the injections were handled by the /** @ngInject */ statements.

Comment: So i already have an index.modules which lists all the modules.

Comment: @devon93 - Ok, then if it still isn't working then you may need to share a plunker of your relevant code if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your help in looking in to this. After a bit of messing around i found duplicate variables and names in other files which were screwing things up. So rather than using vm i used contact and all is good.